# Element hidden on phones, but not desktop responsive layout

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, css

I'm working on a client's website, and we have an issue that has eluded me for a week.

Basically, We have a line of text that is disappearing entirely on mobile devices but is visible in the responsive layout on google inspector with phones selected.

This is confirmed using a Galaxy S5, an LG Optimus L70, as well as iPhone 6.

The section in question is highlighted in red:

[image: The Awards section disappears on mobile devices]

You can see this for yourself at [Their Site](http://www.lewertlaw.com/)

I'll note that we did not develop this site from the ground up, but instead, we are editing their older site. They used a plugin to obtain a mobile version of the site, which we are no longer using (It has been removed).

Since it is not reproduced on the responsive inspector, pinpointing the issue is difficult. Is there an inspector specific to phones?

I have scoured the CSS files for answers, but I was unable to find anything that would point to the element being hidden on phones only. My guess is some sort of residual Javascript or PHP is hiding it, left over from the old plugin.

I've added this line, but it still does not respond.

```
 <?php
    if(!wp_is_mobile()){
 ?>
      <strong class="title"><a href="http://www.lewertlaw.com/awards-distinctions">awards and distinctions</a></strong>
  <?php
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: I see it fine on iPhone 6s, chrome

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I accidently added a ! to that field, effectively making it render "If it is NOT mobile." :/

Can't believe it took me a week to see that.